# Flowable<List<T>> to List<T>

Tags: android, kotlin, observable

I want to convert a FlowableList to a List. Any suggestions?

```
private val flowableList: Flowable<List<T>>
private val list = listOf<T>(flowableList)
```

Comment: you will get simple list in flatMap or in subscribe, you can access as .blockingGet() or blockingFirst() property, but it is a bad practice

Answer (score 2):

Just use `toList` method

```
val list = flowableList.toList().map { it.flatten() }
```

Comment: this gives me a Single<(Mutable)List<List<T>!>!>!

Comment: Yep, you should wait for async stuff anyways. If you want to wait for it in blocking way, you can use `blockingGet()`. @gpunto is completely right about `flatten()`. So final solution will be `flowableList.toList().blockingGet().flatten()` I guess